# How to find last index of shortest run in an Array?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have worked out following logic.  Shortest Run: a subarray of original array having same elements.

```
// "A" is Array, p is length of a current run, q is global variable that stores lowest run length
procedure(){
    while( i < sizeOfArray){
     if(A[i]==A[i+1]){
     //1.Increment a variable "p" to capture the length of run
      //2. compare p and q and which ever is smaller , is saved into q
      }else{
     //3. What to do here ?
     } 
    }
return q;
}
```

Comment: Still not valid C code. Your question states that your logic "always returns wrong." What does this mean, if you haven't written any code yet? The relevant logic is not expressed in what you have shown. You will need to show some effort to get anyone to help with this.

Comment: @DavidBowling I rephrased the question. the motive to ask question is to get to know the logic not the programming code. You can use any language to show the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "Shortest run" based on your code means the shortest sequence in the array where all the numbers are the same. The algorithm below will find the last index of the shortest row. Note that it finds the first shortest run, given that there are multiple runs of the same size.

```
int A[10] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3};
int q = INT_MAX, i = 0, p = 1, lastIndex = 0;
while( i != 9 ){ //10 is the size of the array
        if(A[i]==A[i+1]){
                ++p;
        }else{
                if(p < q) {
                        q = p;
                        lastIndex = i;
                }
                p = 1; //reset p, the size of the run should be 1
        }
        i++;
}
return lastIndex;
```

Note that to find the shortest run, you compare p and q after the run is over, so you compare them in the else statement. The above example returns 6, where A[6] is 2, the last index of the smallest run, which is of size 3.

Comment: Not a good practice to answer questions that show no effort and merely ask for a solution.

Comment: I think the general idea is correct, but there are some errors. E.g. array index out of bounds, I would start at i = 1 and compare with i-1, to avoid that trap. Or you miss it if the last run is the smallest. No downvotes from me.

Comment: The logic fails when the final run is shortest, since `p` is not compared with `q` when the loop terminates . For example, `A[10] = {1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3}` fails, reporting 3.